# Unable to bypass insecure certificate warning with Firefox using Watir

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, watir, geckodriver

I don't seem to be able to ignore any certificate warnings using the Firefox driver with Watir 6.2.0. Is this unexpected behavior, or am I just not using the API properly?

**Example code**:

```
require 'watir'

profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
profile.assume_untrusted_certificate_issuer = false

browser = Watir::Browser.new(:firefox, :profile => profile)

browser.goto 'https://self-signed.badssl.com/
```

**Unexpected result**:

```
/Users/bshannon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.3.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:69:in `assert_ok': Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError
    from /Users/bshannon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.3.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:32:in `initialize'
    from /Users/bshannon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.3.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:83:in `new'
    from /Users/bshannon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.3.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:83:in `create_response'
    from /Users/bshannon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.3.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:107:in `request'
    from /Users/bshannon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.3.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:61:in `call'
    from /Users/bshannon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.3.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/w3c_bridge.rb:620:in `execute'
    from /Users/bshannon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.3.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/w3c_bridge.rb:126:in `get'
    from /Users/bshannon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.3.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/navigation.rb:32:in `to'
    from /Users/bshannon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/watir-6.2.0/lib/watir/browser.rb:78:in `goto'
    from /Users/bshannon/Desktop/test.rb:8:in `<main>'
```

[image]

**Environment:**

```
Watir 6.2.0
Selenium Webdriver 3.3.0
Geckodriver 0.15
Firefox 52.0
Mac OSX
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this via [desired capabilities](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/DesiredCapabilities).  There's additional documentation at https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Ruby-Bindings#ssl-certificates.

```
require 'watir'
capabilities = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.firefox(accept_insecure_certs: true)

browser = Watir::Browser.new(:firefox, :desired_capabilities => capabilities)
browser.goto 'https://self-signed.badssl.com/'
puts browser.url                               #=> https://self-signed.badssl.com/
browser.close
```

Comment: The capability is defined in the w3c spec https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/webdriver-spec.html#capabilities and in the geckodriver readme https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver. Capabilities in ruby are just snake_case versions of the json camelCase capabilities

Comment: Also, when using geckodriver, you should try and use `Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::W3CCapabilities` instead. This will change in the future but that is how it is now

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
profile.accept_untrusted_certificates = true
profile.assume_untrusted_certificate_issuer = true
```

Comment: I receive the following error when trying this:

'<main>': undefined method 'accept_untrusted_certificates=' for #<Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile:0x007fd10494b088> (NoMethodError)

Comment: can you try:
    webdriver_accept_untrusted_certs  = true
    webdriver_assume_untrusted_issuer  = true

Comment: Unfortunately, no luck with that either. Do you have any other ideas as to what the issue might be? It seems like it should trust self signed certificates by default based on what I'm reading in the docs?

Comment: The only other suggestion i have is to set the marionette capability to true

Comment: Don't use Geckodriver, it has so many problems so downgrade your Firefox to 47.0.2 and use legacy firebox driver, everything works fine.

Comment: @Gopal Yeah, it does look like downgrading like you've suggested is the  path of least resistance at this time.

Comment: @Bob Yes, In my case it's not even selecting select list and also it releases the controls after the click immediately,it doesn't hold the control like legacy Firefox driver does for page refreshing ,navigation.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Chrome instead, then you need to do this instead:

```
Watir::Browser.new(:chrome, switches: ['--ignore-certificate-errors'])
```

Answer (score 0):

These days (in Watir 7.1 & selenium webdriver 4.1.0) I was able to achieve this by supplying `accept_insecure_certs` in Watir options:

```
profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
profile.proxy = Selenium::WebDriver::Proxy.new :http => 192.168.1.2, :ssl => 192.168.1.3
profile['network.http.max-connections'] = 15

options = {
  accept_insecure_certs: true,
  page_load_timeout: 60,
  script_timeout: 60,
  profile: profile,
  args: ['-headless']
}

browser = Watir::Browser.new(:firefox, options: options)
```